# IL to c# conversion

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, il, mono.cecil

I'm working on a project which has very little in the way of testing and where large amounts of the code has recently been changed. In particular code has been ported from using one data provider to another and DataSet have been replaced with DTO's.

I would now like to test this as much as possible, but can't realistically create tests for all the changes which have been made by numerous people in a time frame required.

Using Mono.cecil I have been able to write a test which finds all the database calls and the relevant stored procedure name and compares the parameters defined in the c# with those in the database.

I would like to take this one step further and actually call the method, even if all the parameters were defaults. This way although the DataReader might not have any rows I could discover the schema and try to compare this to the static mapper methods.

eg

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var Divisions = (from IDataRecord record in reader.GetRows() 
select RecordMapper.GetDivisionFromRecord(record)).ToList();
```

Where GetRows() is a simple extension method and GetDivisionFromRecord is static method which looks a bit like this

```
public static Division GetDivisionFromRecord(record)
{
  return new Division
  {
       Id = record.GetValueOrDefault<long?>("id"),
       Name = record.GetValueOrDefault<string>("name")
  };
}
```

Unfortunatley I can't figure out how to convert from the IL references to cached static delegates back to the name of the static method in the mapper class.
If I could find the method name then I could then use Cecil to Get the method and find the callvirt opcodes to GetValueOrDefault so I could build a collection of database aliases and types.

The IL looks like this.

```
IL_0025: callvirt instance class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataReader IOracleHelper::ExecuteReader(class OracleCommandWrapper)
IL_002a: stloc.0
IL_002b: ldloc.0
IL_002c: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord> NullSafeExtensions::GetRows(class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataReader)
IL_0031: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Cast<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerable)
IL_0036: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord, class [Services.Common]Division> DataDao::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate17'
IL_003b: brtrue.s IL_0050
IL_003d: ldnull
IL_003e: ldftn class [Services.Common]Division DataDao::'<GetAlDivisions>b__16'(class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord)
IL_0044: newobj instance void class [System.Core]System.Func`2<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord, class [Services.Common]Division>::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_0049: stsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord, class [Services.Common]Division> DataDao::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate17'
IL_004e: br.s IL_0050
IL_0050: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Func`2<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord, class [Services.Common]Division> DataDao::'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate17'
IL_0055: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!1> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Select<class [System.Data]System.Data.IDataRecord, class [Services.Common]Division>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [System.Core]System.Func`2<!!0, !!1>)
IL_005a: call class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!0> [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ToList<class [Services.Common]Division>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)
```

I have used both cecil and reflection and can see the CachedAnonymousDelegates as private static fields. But I can see how to obtain actual method call.

Any ideas how I can pull this off ?

Comment: Telerik provides a free decompiler if you just want to decompile the .NET assemblies.  It would probably save you some time.  And it's still free, unlike Reflector.  http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx  (And I'm in no way associated with Telerk, so no relaitonship to disclose).

Comment: This is a strange way to go about it.  Just run a diff on the versions in source control to find out what you ought to test.

Comment: I'm already using a decompiler, mono.cecil. I do not want to use a tool such as Reflector / ILSpy etc, since then the whole testing process would be manual and I would not have a test case which could used for regression testing and to validate any database releases etc...

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used AstBuilder from ICSharpCode.Decompiler and ICSharpCode.NRefactory to transform the relevant IL from Mono.cecil back to c# so I can use a regex to discover the mapper.

Using this approach I use all of this metadata to generate the hundreds of tests which should have been done in the first place.